# Scala weird printing out toString() override

Tags: scala, overriding, tostring

```
class Complex(real: Double, imaginary: Double) {
    def re = real
    def im = imaginary
    override def toString() : String =
      "" + re + (if (im < 0) "" else "+") + im + "i"
  }
object Runme {
  // making a new starting point...
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var c = new Complex(2.3, 4.5)
    print(c)
  }
}
```

When I run this code, why do I get "Complex@3834d63f" instead of "2.3+4.5i"?

Comment: Works for me.  Have you left out some important detail?

Comment: Oh I had accidentally nested the class Complex declaration inside another class Complex declaration. It works as expected now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had accidentally nested the class Complex declaration inside another class Complex declaration. This question is now resolved.